# ApexSQL Diff - All text on one line

Tags: sql-server, encoding

We just started using ApexSQL Diff and we've run into a problem when comparing two database files that have a line or two changed.
On the left side, all of the text is on one line.  It might be due to some carriage return encoding issue, but I can't find where to resolve that in ApexSQL Diff.
Has anyone else experienced this problem?
http://imgur.com/yjf7snN

Comment: Please, include relevant code in the question as it is harder to read from the image and the link might also break in the future.

Comment: I believe there are some options that let you ignore white characters or event carriage returns.